# Delete k8s resources of a service deployed through "jx preview" and "jx promote" respectively in "preview" and "jx-staging" environments

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-x

I am deploying the services using "jx preview" and "jx promote" commands respectively in "preview" and "jx-staging" in Jenkins-X.

I want to delete the resources (like deployments, services, pv's and pvc's etc) associated with that particular micro service deployed using jx commands.

Because when I deploy the same service in both "preview" and "jx-staging" environments the build fails because the service is already running on one port deployed in one of the namespaces.

So I want to delete the service resources (like deployments, services, pv's and pvc's etc) after it is deployed.

Please let me know the command to delete the resources associated with a micro service that is being deployed.

Answer (score 0):

resources associated with Preview environments are garbage collected when the Pull Request associated with a Preview is closed. This works via a background `CronJob` which runs the [jx gc previews](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_gc_previews/) command. You can eagerly run this yourself too.

If you really want to delete a preview by hand manually you can use [jx delete preview](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_delete_preview/).

The above works for previews. If you want to remove something from Staging or Production just modify the `env/requirements.yaml` file via a pull request or use [jx delete application](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_delete_application/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using "jx step helm delete <release_name> -n <namespace>" to delete all the resources associated with a release. This deletes deployments, services, pvc's but unable to delete pv's. Any suggestions please